# Why there is only getter for WebAssembly.Memory.buffer? What's the underlying mechanism if the buffer is SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, sharedarraybuffer

As we can setup WebAssembly memory as a shared memory via `WebAssembly.Memory`:

```
wasmMemory = new WebAssembly.Memory({
    "initial": NUMBER,
    "maximum": NUMBER,
    "shared": true
});
```

`WebAssembly.Memory.buffer` only has a getter, so I **cannot** do the following:

```
buff =  new SharedArrayBuffer(NUMBER);
wasmMemory.buffer = buff;
```

**First Question**:

Is there any reason it designs like that. I've checked the [SPEC](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/js-api/#memories) but found no answer.

Maybe the underlying implementations of **normal** `SharedArrayBuffer` and wasm's `SharedArrayBuffer` though their `instanceof`s are the same?

Or are there other things results in this design?

**Second Question**:

Is there any magic way to put existed `SharedArrayBuffer` in the `WebAssembly.Memory`?

I want to do this because I have a new class that extends from the original `SharedArrayBuffer`, and I would like to use it in wasm as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any official explanation for this either, but if I had to guess, it's because your custom buffer would be automatically replaced with the default buffer everytime memory is grown.

Comment: I looked up the implementation of V8. Seems the underlying buffers of WASM are the same as JS's.`wasm-objects.cc`: 
`Handle<JSArrayBuffer> buffer = (shared == SharedFlag::kShared) ? isolate->factory()->NewJSSharedArrayBuffer(std::move(backing_store)) : isolate->factory()->NewJSArrayBuffer(std::move(backing_store));`

Comment: btw. I thought your guess sounds reasonable.

Comment: I also saw a recent announcement where due to solving Spectre exploits they brought back SharedArrayBuffers and said WebAssembly buffer would now be a SharedArrayBuffer.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted. Buffers are managed by the WebAssembly.Memory implementation and can be swapped on growth, which is why you can't provide your own.